# How to get unique array with only filter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have an array:

```
var a = [2,3,4,5,5,4]
```

I want to get unique array out of given array like

```
b = [2,3,4,5]
```

I have tried

```
a.filter(function(d){return b.indexOf(d)>-1})
```

and I don't want to use for loop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Comment: Here are multiple examples - http://www.jstips.co/en/deduplicate-an-array/ with newer ES syntax, and future implementations (using Array Sets)

Comment: use lodash library ( https://lodash.com/docs/#uniq)

Answer (score 14):

You can simply do it in JavaScript, with the help of the second - index - parameter of the `filter` method:

```
var a = [2,3,4,5,5,4];
a.filter(function(value, index){ return a.indexOf(value) == index });
```

Comment: I will be happy if u explain this "function(d,i){return a.indexOf(d)==i}"

Comment: i in parameter is for indexing , means when you check for second last 5 , index would be 4 but indexOf would be 3 so they dont match hence it wiill filter out

Comment: Thanks.You have given a simple,tricky and great answer to this problem

Answer (score 6):

This is not an Angular related problem. It can be resolved in a couple of ways depending which libraries you are using.

If you are using jquery:

```
var uniqeElements = $.unique([2,3,4,5,5,4]);
```

The output would be:

```
[2,3,4,5]
```

If you are using underscore:

```
var uniqeElements = _.uniq([2,3,4,5,5,4]);
```

Same output.

And pure JS code:

```
var unique = [2,3,4,5,5,4].filter(function(elem, index, self) {
    return index == self.indexOf(elem);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var b = a.filter( function( item, index, inputArray ) {
       return inputArray.indexOf(item) == index;
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code

Comment: Please Refer Yaser Adel Mehraban sloution